# UpdateModel with different source and destination types

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my action I use a `InsertPerson` model that has the following properties:

```
pulbic class InsertPerson
{
     [Required]
     public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

and I have a DTO model that is passed to my repository:

```
public class PersonDto
{
     public int Id{get;set;}
     public string Name{get;set;}
     public string LastName{get;set;}
}
```

my action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(InsertPerson insertPerson)
{
     if(ModelState.IsValid){
           var personDto = new PersonDto();

           UpdateModel(personDto)
           //UpdateModel(personDto, "insertPerson") I've tried this too

     }

}
```

why it doesn't work(after UpdateModel all properties is still null)?

Is there any way to update my `personDto` using `UpdateModel`?

I know about AutoMapper but I think it's boring to use in controller.

---

My view:

```
@model Help_Desk.ViewModel.InsertPersonViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InsertPerson.Name)

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

and my viewmodel:

```
public class InsertPersonViewModel
{
    public InsertPerson InsertPerson{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is that after UpdateModel all properties of personDto is null.

Comment: Maybe also provide the code for `UpdateModel` ...?

Comment: UpdateModel is a System.Web.Mvc.Controller method.

Comment: Does insertPerson have the value?

Comment: You should show us your view code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now we see the problem.  The information that was missing is that you were using a View Model, and the View Model creates a "container" of sorts that must be accounted for in the UpdateModel.

What's happening is that UpdateModel is trying to literally update "InsertPerson.Name" in your personDto object.  Since that doesn't exist, it's not working.

You can fix this by specifying `UpdateModel(personDto, "InsertPerson")`

Comment: @murilokunze - that should work.  Check your generated html, and look at the name attribute of the input tag, if it's "InsertPerson.Name" then the above code should work.

Comment: Yeah, the name attribute is correct. Unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: @murilokunze - I see in your code above you use "insertPerson" and not "InsertPerson".  In general, this shouldn't be case sensitive but the prefix might be when using UpdateModel.

Comment: @murilokunze - so the prefix was case sensitive?